# How is a boolean evaluated in a java if else statement?

Tags: java, types, boolean

Why is b, after the `if` statement in class **Test01**, true -- yet b, after the `else if` statement in class **Test02**, appears not to be true?

```
/* Evaluate the two classes below independently of one another*/    

class Test01 {
  public static void main(String[] args){   
    boolean b = true; 
    if (b) 
      System.out.println("B");
  }
}


class Test02 {
  public static void main(String[] args){   
    boolean b = true; 
    if (b = false) 
      System.out.println("A");
    else if (b) 
      System.out.println("B");
  }
}
```

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings and you will get your answer.

Comment: you are assinging value not evalutating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mix operators.

`if (b = false)` is an assignment operator.

`if (b == false)` is an equality comparator.

You may also write it :  `if (!b)`

You can refer to [operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

When you write :

```
boolean b = true;
if (b = false)
    System.out.println("A");
else if (b)
    System.out.println("B");
```

The JVM executes the conditional statements in this order :

- `b = false` is evaluated and so the `b` variable refers now to the `false` value
- `if (b)` is evaluated to `false` so the conditional statement is `false`.
- `else if (b)` is also evaluated to `false` so the conditional statement is `false`.

So nothing is displayed.

Comment: Nah. Its yours. My mistake. You made it clear ... My understanding is that, b is a local variable. There is only one copy of it so statements impact it chronologically within its method block.

Comment: @vee You get it. `b` mutates at a time, so its value is then reflected in next statements that use it.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are doing `if (b = false)`. Where as you have to do if `(b == false)`. When you do `=` it just assigns `false` to `b` and in the next condition is fails to go inside of if.

Comment: Probably telling him that he has to do `if (!b)` would be better.

Comment: @Oleg Since OP is already confused with `= vs ==`. clearing that for now Do not want to add more confusion :).

Comment: @GhostCat how do you know this is a typo and OP knows this already ?? Did OP told you ?

Comment: Give the title by OP, I jumped to answer to clear the confusion. Feel free to mark this as a dupe if you have one. I'll vote too.

Comment: @GhostCat I voted the question for typo too as you did. So you got 3 supporters so far and need another 1 vote to close.  Have a good rest of the the day.

Answer (score 1):

Because the "result" of an assignment is the value assigned.So it's still a boolean expression in the second case and now in this case `b` is `false`.

```
if (b = false)
```

will be evaluated as

```
if(false) //you are assigning false to the b so the control will go to the else block
```

Answer (score -2):

you can not apply = in if statement you have to use == like this if(b==false)

Comment: One can sure do that. Yes doing so is wrong here - but it is obvious that he "can" do it. It is possible - but simply leading to an unexpected result.

Comment: Bingo. The unexpected result is what is puzzling to me ...

Comment: why not assignment to a Boolean is allowed in if condition